# How to correctly calculate struct size using Marshal.SizeOf() in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling

I'm banging my head with this one.
I have a C# structure:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct Enroll
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 101)]
        public char[] Name;
        public UInt16 Port;
        public byte Num;
        public byte Max;
        public UInt64 Version;
        public byte TS;
        public byte Avg;
        public byte Flags;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 16)]
        public char[] Tag;
    }
```

Which totals to 132 bytes.
However

```
S.Enroll X = new();
int size = Marshal.SizeOf(X);
```

calculates 144 bytes, thus preventing me from successfully mapping bytes to structure.

Sender is an C++ application with structure declared like this:

```
struct Enroll
{
public:
    char Name[101] = { 0 };
    uint16 Port = 0;
    uint8 Num = 0;
    uint8 Max = 0;
    uint64 Version = 0;
    uint8 TS = 0;
    uint8 Avg = 0;
    DevFlags Flags = DevFlags ::None;
    char Tag[16] = { 0 };
};
```

Which results in actual 132 bytes which I can read one by one.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: You are missing [`Pack=1`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.pack?view=net-5.0), i.e.: `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=1)]`

Comment: Thanks, its OK now. So, for future reference; what does Pack=1 do exactly?

Comment: See [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.pack).

Comment: @MickyD OP explicitly says this is for C++ interop; something like protobuf would be an unnecessary indirection here (although if it was me, I might consider "fixed buffers" instead of those `char[]`)

Comment: @TomislavPlečko Click the link in my comment above. It takes you to the documentation for Pack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Matthew Watson suggested, Pack=1 fixed my issue. [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.pack?view=net-5.0) by Sinatr explains:

> The Pack field controls the alignment of a type's fields in memory. It
> affects LayoutKind.Sequential. By default, the value is 0, indicating
> the default packing size for the current platform. The value of Pack
> must be 0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, or 128:
>
> The fields of a type instance are aligned by using the following
> rules:
>
> The alignment of the type is the size of its largest element (1, 2, 4,
> 8, etc., bytes) or the specified packing size, whichever is smaller.
>
> Each field must align with fields of its own size (1, 2, 4, 8, etc.,
> bytes) or the alignment of the type, whichever is smaller. Because the
> default alignment of the type is the size of its largest element,
> which is greater than or equal to all other field lengths, this
> usually means that fields are aligned by their size. For example, even
> if the largest field in a type is a 64-bit (8-byte) integer or the
> Pack field is set to 8, Byte fields align on 1-byte boundaries, Int16
> fields align on 2-byte boundaries, and Int32 fields align on 4-byte
> boundaries.
>
> Padding is added between fields to satisfy the alignment requirements.